# Number of rational points in a non-smooth variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$ with dimensional $n$. We know that if $X$ is smooth than $X$ has about $q^{nk}$ rational points over $\mathbb{F}_{q^k}$ (Weil hypothesis). Is there an analogous statement for non-smooth varieties?

Comment: Yes a similar property holds whenever $X$ is geometrically integral. Search google for the "Lang-Weil estimate".

Comment: You can assume $X$ reduced, and then $X$ has a smooth dense open $U$. Let $Z=X\setminus U$, which has dimension $\leq n-1$. If you accept the asymptotic for smooth varieties, by induction on $n$ you get that $\# X(\mathbb{F}_{q^k}) = \# U(\mathbb{F}_{q^k}) + \# Z(\mathbb{F}_{q^k}) = (1+o(1))q^{nk} + O(q^{(n-1)k}) = (1+o(1)) q^{nk}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Daniel Loughran's comment, I found [this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/the-lang-weil-bound/) very nice exposition by Terence Tao which seems to answer the question in detail.